# Assigning resources in PHP without letting two people access

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a system that assigns a given resource to users. This system is accessed by thousands of people every day.

In our DB table that has records of these resources we have a column that lets us know if that resource is already assigned.

When an API request comes in to assign the resource, we run a query to find an unassigned resource. The next line of code is a check if that returned a false so we can show an error. The next line after that if locks that resource to that user. We are talking 1-2ms at most between finding and then assigning.

I'm worried that with the amount of traffic coming in, it's possible that more than one user could be returned that same resource. We have a deterministic algorithm that will return the same resource every time we ask for one.

Is there a good way to ensure that it's impossible for two people to be returned the same instance?

My underlying system is Laravel 5.8, running in AWS. Load balanced (Application ELB), multiple app servers, multiple worker servers. DB is Postgres running on RDS. Redis for caching and queue management.

Comment: Read up on optimistic and pessimistic locking strategies and pick the one that best applies in your situation. 1-2ms is *a tiny eternity* as far as computers are concerned. It may seem like nothing to you but for a machine that operates on the nanosecond scale that's like standing around for ten minutes.

Comment: This lead me down the path. Eventually I found a way to update and do the select in one query, which gets rid of any possible race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you will have to acquire a lock on the data; enclosed within a transaction on DB-level. @tadman is right. However, the hints might only be a starting point for your high-load-system, since I understand, that you need to acquire costly table-locks.

Therefore, you might run against the next limit:  concurrent transactions; resulting in dead-locks in the worst case. 
You can assess / guesttimate this risk by looking on how many "assignment-requests" (your API-Endpoint-response) are actually to answered per minute.

I would then split the problem, if necessary:

- have a very fast "stack of unassigned resources": assign concrete resource, check in the moment of writing whether it is still unassigned / in the pool; if not, take next (or explicitly the last) from "fast-stack"
- fill the fast stack asynchronously, so that its pool size is always "sufficient"